# Groupby multiple column to find the unique count of one column using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like:

```
column1    column2    column3
 ram        tall        good
 rohan      short       fine
 ajay       tall        best
 alia       tall        good
 aman       medium      fine
 john       short       good
 jack       short       fine
```

now i need output like:

unique count of good in tall, short, medium on basis of column1->

```
tall=2 , short=1 , medium=0
```

unique count of fine in tall, short, medium on basis of column1->

```
tall=0 , short=2 , medium=1
```

unique count of best in tall, short, medium on basis of column1->

```
tall=1 , short=0 , medium=0
```

I am beginner in pandas. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
res = df[['column3', 'column2']].value_counts().unstack('column2', fill_value=0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
column2  medium  short  tall
column3                     
best          0      0     1
fine          1      2     0
good          0      1     2
```

As an alternative [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + *unstack*:

```
res = df.groupby(['column3', 'column2']).count().unstack('column2', fill_value=0)
print(res)
```

**Output** *(groupby)*

```
        column1           
column2  medium short tall
column3                   
best          0     0    1
fine          1     2    0
good          0     1    2
```

The idea behind both approaches is to create an *index* and then unstack it. If you want to match the same order as specify in your question, convert to Categorical first:

```
df['column2'] = pd.Categorical(df['column2'], categories=['tall', 'short', 'medium'], ordered=True)
res = df[['column3', 'column2']].value_counts().unstack('column2', fill_value=0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
column2  tall  short  medium
column3                     
best        1      0       0
fine        0      2       1
good        2      1       0
```

Comment: Thanks dani, one small doubt if i have same row multiple times in dataframe, then to find count can i replace .value_counts() with nunique() ?

Comment: If you want to count the duplicates I would say use .value_counts, notice that you have the [fine, short] column 2 times

Comment: yes correct, but for [fine, short] the column1 name is different. So it will be count as different rows. Okay got it thanks

Answer (score 5):

Let's try [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['column3'], df['column2'])
```

---

```
column2  medium  short  tall
column3                     
best          0      0     1
fine          1      2     0
good          0      1     2
```